# Host same Win32 window within multiple WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I want to show the same Win32 window within different WPF user controls at the same time, is this possible?

I have an application with a main WPF Window with multiple child user controls. I modify the visibility of these user controls so only one of them is visible at a given moment. Two of these user controls contain a binding with the control that hosts a Win32 window (inherited from HwndHost), but when running the application I only see the Win32 window when visualizing the first of these user controls. Am I missing something?

Comment: Adding more specific information to your question may help you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A window in Win32 can't be displayed in two different places.

Comment: That is certainly what I believe as well but WPF is a weird beast, I could easily believe that WPF would cause the win32 window to render to an off-screen DC and then copy that into wherever WPF wants it to show. After all, as far as I am aware WPF window trees generally only have a single HWND for the whole tree.